# Unable to fix broken apps on linux mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I'm not able to install,remove and update packeges in my "Linux Mint VERSION="20.1 (Ulyssa)",
I got that issue after update mysql-cluster-community-server and other related mysql packages.

I have tried these solucions to resolve this issue but couldn't resolve it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-59 linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-60
  linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic mysql-community-client-core
mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-community-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
mysql-cluster-community-client-core mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins
mysql-cluster-community-server-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mysql-cluster-community-client-core mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins
mysql-cluster-community-server-core
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 158 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 452340 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins (8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_ldap_sasl_client.so', which is also in package mysql-community-client-plugins 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-cluster-community-client-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-cluster-community-client-core (8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-client-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql', which is also in package mysql-community-client-core 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-cluster-community-server-core (8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ibd2sdi', which is also in package mysql-community-server-core 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-client-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

These are broken apps

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-cluster-community-client:
 mysql-cluster-community-client depends on mysql-cluster-community-client-core (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-cluster-community-client-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-cluster-community-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:
 mysql-client depends on mysql-cluster-community-client (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-cluster-community-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-cluster-community-server:
 mysql-cluster-community-server depends on mysql-client (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-client is not configured yet.
 mysql-cluster-community-server depends on mysql-cluster-community-server-core (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-cluster-community-server-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-cluster-community-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-cluster-community-server (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-cluster-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-cluster-community-client
 mysql-client
 mysql-cluster-community-server
 mysql-server
```

I have also tried to remove those apps in this way..

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-cluster-community-client : Depends: mysql-cluster-community-client-core (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-cluster-community-server : Depends: mysql-cluster-community-server-core (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu18.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to purged complement mysql then redo a clean installation on your system

Comment: Please provide more details like commands, and any other explanation you could. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I found the solution,
I had manually remove broken packages from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

You have to purge mysql-cluster-community-client and mysql-cluster-community-server.

```
sudo dpkg --purge mysql-cluster-community-client

sudo dpkg --purge mysql-cluster-community-server

sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server

sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-client-core
```

After that, you will have MySQL uninstalled from your distro